# Existing implementations of removing redundant linear constraints (python)

Tags: python, constraints, linear-programming

I have constraints given by Ax > 0. I am wondering whether there are any ready-to-use implementations available that remove redundant constraints. By redundant constraints I mean constraints such that the feasible set is the same after removing them. I have seen that [scipy.optimize.linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) has the "rr_method" option, but these methods, e.g. "pivot", only remove linearly dependent constraints, and not other redundant constraints. Are there any such implementations available?

Comment: The better LP solvers have a "presolver" that tries to remove unneeded rows and columns. These are not the simplest pieces of software. But that also means that you don't have to implement that yourself: the LP solver does it for you. Presolvers often do a very good job and are essential in commercial LP solvers.

Comment: Are those "better LP solvers" available somewhere/open source?

Comment: There are some open-source implementations. You already found scipy linprog. Others include COIN-OR CLP, HiGHS, SCIP. May not be always easy to read and understand the source code.

Comment: Addition to Erwins comments: [PaPILO](https://github.com/lgottwald/PaPILO) is probably the most promising open-source presolver project right now (and linked to HiGHS and SCIP).